# Trying to offset a max indirect value in excel and running into problems

Tags: excel, match, offset, excel-indirect

Hopefully someone can help figure out why this statement doesn't work

I am trying to return a value 1 row down from the max value

```
=offset(MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(80,MATCH(B5,INDIRECT(B4),0)+4,1,TRUE,B4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(80,MATCH(B6,INDIRECT(B4),0)+4,4,TRUE,B4))),1,0)
```

Comment: offset requires an address in the first parameter, not a numerical maximum. show sample data together with expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
=INDEX(TheRangeToSearch,MATCH(MAX(TheRangeToSearch),TheRangeToSearch,0)+1)
```

Change `TheRangeToSearch` to reference the range containing values you want to find the maximum of.